# problem trying to run HP driver file from command line

Tags: drivers

I'm trying to run the HP driver file for my HP Officejet Pro 6978 which has stopped working since I installed the "update" for it this morning. If I type "./hplip-3.20.11.run" it says permission denied. So I enter my admin password, retype it and it says "no such command" If I try double clicking it, it opens the program text.

Comment: If you have not done so, make the file executable by running `chmod +x hplip-3.20.11.run` in the terminal after you `cd` to the directory containing the file and then try running it again.

Comment: You do not need latest HPLIP, [only >=3.16.8](https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/supported_devices/index). What is your Ubuntu version?